# Vuex returning some data back the the component

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

I have an axios call in my vuex actions

```
  return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `/myurl`,

    }).then(function (response) {
      context.commit('value', response.data.data);
    }),
```

However this is called in my component

```
this.$store.dispatch("fetchmystuff")
```

How do I return a value to the component?

In the past I have attached the then() to the dispatch

```
 this.$store.dispatch("fetchmystuff")
    .then(function (response) {
     //do some component stuff
 }),
```

but I would like to run the commit first in vuex,  then return something to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've dispatched the action `fetchmystuff`.
From within your component, you will want to either.

#### 1. query the store for the state of `value`

```
computed: {   
  value() {    
    return this.$store.state.value
  } 
}
```

#### 2.  call a getter which gets the state of `value` from a computed property

> in component

```
computed: {   
  value() {    
    return this.$store.getters.value
  } 
}
```

> in store getters.js

```
getters: {
  // ...
  value: (state, getters) => {
    return getters.value
  }
}
```

The dispatcher/action shouldn't need to access to the component
(as state is only set in store via mutations/commits, and have state passed to other components via getters).

This allows a decoupling of concerns between the store and the component parts of your application.

Comment: Thanks that was kind of how I did it in other places, it just seemed an 'alternative' way to go! I though I could have done it without checking the $store.state.

Comment: Yes you're correct that you can remove the instances of store from the `axios fetch` method - so this is the trade off you need to make when leveraging `Vuex` store (reusable methods via actions or leaving the method isolated within a component)

Comment: In my case, the component might exist twice (regular and sometimes in modal div). Both components must have different states, that can be modified by a dispatched functions return value. So one state of value won't work, because in this case, both components values would be the same from $store.state. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you asked this question SO @Dong3000

Comment: @DenisTsoi I've made it concrete here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842269/capsuled-data-sharing-with-vuex-axios-several-component-instances